# iPhone 5 Power Button Replacement Programme

Tags: iphone, warranty

I have an iPhone 5 (out of warranty) which is *eligible* for a power button replacement via the Apple programme.

I smashed my screen a while ago, and to be frank don't feel paying Apple £200 to replace it is a fair price, so being that I have the know-how anyway, I replaced it myself with a £40 screen off of eBay.

My question, being that Apple replace the button for iPhone's out of warranty, will they refuse to fix the button due to me *breaking the warranty* by opening the phnoe myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two facts that might disappoint you:

1. The damage done on your iPhone may be responsible for the broken power button.
2. The iPhone may not have been opened before (by non authorised personal)

I just got my phone to the Apple store for a power button replacement, I had have a small crack in my screen, but never replaced it. They looked for water damage and told me I was able to let them replace my power button. They did not mind about the small crack.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. I think you're confirming my queries that they won't fix the button due to it being opened by non-authorised personnel, however I'm not 100% sure what you mean by the first point?

Comment: The first point is like this. If there is exorbitant damage to your screen, this also might responsible for the damage of the power button. If there is little damage to your screen, this might not be responsible for the broken power botton.

Comment: I see, so even though their programme says my phone is eligible, they could still refuse to fix the button due to the broken screen?
If so, will they know if I replace the screen myself before they fix the power button?

Comment: It depends on the replacement screen. There are original screens and non-original screens. Furthermore, screws are usually replaced with new ones. So Apple could check for the screen serial number and could check the screws for damage. But if I was you, just go to the store, submit it to the program and say it has never been openend. They will contact you if your phone can not be repaired for free.